# Queueable interface to chain Apex batch jobs

Tags: batch, scheduled-job, asyncapexjob

Can we use the Apex Queueable interface to chain batch jobs? 
I am planning to invoke a Apex Queueable interface from the finish method of a batch job. The Queueable interface would queue the Apex batch Job to be chained.

Comment: Just wondering - why do you need to use Queueable? Why not just invoke the next batch from the finish?

Comment: Well If I invoke the next batch job from finish method it might fail if there are 5 jobs running in the Org. Another approach would be to schedule it from the finish method but with that design the job might fail to execute due to the max 5 jobs in queue, processing limit.

Comment: I think most, if not all orgs are running the flex queue now, so that would alleviate some of that concern, since you can add 100 jobs to the Batch queue. I would check for that limit, and if there are > 100, schedule a class to run in x mins, check the queue again, and if there is room, put it in - otherwise, schedule for later...

Comment: Yes.. Enabling Apex Flex Queue would be the ideal solution. But it might take some time before this functionality is enabled in our Org. In the interim I am trying to leverage the Queueable interface.